# Is there a way to edit the size of on image on Cloudinary without changing the url?

Tags: cloudinary

I am optimizing a small website with images hosted on Cloudinary.

I would like to reduce all the file sizes of the images in one go without editing the URLs on the website.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to reupload the images while performing [incoming transformations](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#incoming_transformations), where the transformations are applied upon upload rather than on the fly.